# ¿Por qué a la hora de editar las margenes de esta pagina web echa en wordpress no me deja cambiar las margenes de la derecha e izquierda?

Tags: css, wordpress, web, elementor

Estoy creando una pagina web, el problema es que al hacerla responsive no me queda con el espacio que quiero, ya que en algunas computadoras o en algunos portatiles se ven las margenes diferentes, y creo que esto es porque la margen de la derecha y la izquierda me salen como auto, ¿Como puedo cambiarlas? Estoy trabajando en wordpress con elementor.

[image: Margen no se puede editar derecha ni izquierda]

Comment: Simplemente busca la clase y reescribe los css

Answer (score 0):

Los contenedores "container" o "wrapper" por defecto tienen prestablecido el margen de derecha y el de izquierda en "auto", esto es lo que permite centrar el contenido; si cambias estos valores el contenido no se centrara.

Comment: Pero yo no estoy hablando de los contenedores o si a esos te refieres como las secciones me disculpas pero lo que necesito saber es como le puedo quitar ese automático que esta como predeterminado a las secciones.

Answer (score 0):

Dale al botón de la derecha, debajo del rem y podras configurar los margenes.
Si estas trabajando con elementor y wordpress, abajo a la derecha, al lado del botón de actualizar, hay una opción que se llama "modo adaptable". Ahí puedes configurar los margenes según el tamaño de la pantalla.